# Perform two related operations in EF Core

Tags: c#, entity-framework, postgresql, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

In my ASP.NET Core app I have DbContext that contains two types of Entities, say, Pupils and Classes. I want to add a new Class, get the Id of new Class and add a new Pupil to the class.
I tried to do it this way:

```
var Class = new Class{ name = "Math" };
Context.Classes.Add(Class);
await Context.SaveChangesAsync();
var Pupil = new Pupil{ name = "Rem", ClassId = Class.Id };
Context.Pupils.Add(Pupil);
await Context.SaveChangesAsync();
```

However I got the error on the second call to SaveChangesAsync():

> Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext:Error: An exception occurred
>   in the database while saving changes.
>   System.InvalidOperationException: A second operation started on this
>   context before a previous operation completed. Any instance members
>   are not guaranteed to be thread safe.

I tried to wrap everything in transaction this way:

```
using (var transaction = Context.Database.BeginTransaction()) {
    ....
    transaction.Commit();
}
```

But the problem persists.

What is the correct way to perform two related operations in EF Core? Is it possible to do in a single transaction?

PS: I'm using PostgreSQL with Npgsql provider

Comment: Just wondering (blind guess), what happens if you assign the return value of `await Context.SaveChangesAsync()` and do something with it (like, return if it's zero)? Again, blind blind guess...

Comment: Also, you are calling `await` and you are using ASP.NET Core... meaning you are in a controller action when this code executes, right?

Comment: Ops,  wrong guess - it doesn't work and yes, i'm using await

Comment: you are creating a new Context for every request and you are disposing it as soon as you are done with it right?

Comment: Yeah, right. The problem happens when I try to call SaveChangesAsync() more than once

Comment: No idea then :(,  will have to give it a try tomorrow

Comment: 100% sure Context is a local variable and not an instance property?

Comment: Rewrite it as local var Context = Provider.GetService<ShellDbContext>(); and the problem persists

Comment: Try adding the "pupil" instance to the "Pupils" collection of the "class" instance, and call the SaveChangesAsync() only once. See if that works.

Comment: Enable `Debug` logging (in `Startup` or `appsettings`, depends on your app) - this will dump all SQLs into log. Check, what commands are executed - may be you will see something "interesting".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was with using DB somewhere else since ASP.NET Core Dependency Injection creates only single instance of each service.
I solved it by creating a new scope

```
public MyService(IServiceProvider provider) { ... };
....

var Scope = provider.CreateScope();            
var Context = Scope.ServiceProvider.GetService<ShellDbContext>();
```

Comment: This solves the problem. Thu I'm not certain with regards to performance. Here is how I did it.     public class Repository
    {
        public MyDbContext _db;

        public Repository(IServiceProvider provider)
        {
            var Scope = provider.CreateScope();
            _db = Scope.ServiceProvider.GetService<MyDbContext>();
        }
    }

Comment: ServiceLifetime.Transient also solves the issue. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41923804/configuring-dbcontext-as-transient

Answer (score 0):

Is `Class.Id` is autoincrement/sequence field? May be EF is querying DB for it's value after insertion... Try add `Console.WriteLine(Class.Id)` or `await Context.Entry(Class).ReloadAsync()` after first save.