# Blazor A second operation started on this context before a previous operation completed

Tags: asp.net-core, blazor, blazor-server-side, blazor-client-side

I makes the NavMenu dynamically and return menu i the database by users and in the index page already i returned something in the database but when i run the application or reload it show me bellow error

> InvalidOperationException: A second operation started on this context
>   before a previous operation completed. This is usually caused by
>   different threads using the same instance of DbContext. For more
>   information on how to avoid threading issues with DbContext, see
>   https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2097913.

**NavMenu  code,**

```
List<Menu> menus = new List<Menu>();

protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
{ 
    menus  = await MenuService.GetMenus();

}
```

**Index code**

```
@if (priorities == null)
{
    <p><em>Loading...</em></p>
}
else
{
    <table class="table">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Name</th> 
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            @foreach (var priority in priorities)
            {
                <tr>
                    <td>@priority.Name</td>
                </tr>
            }
        </tbody>
    </table>
}

@code { 
    List<Priority> priorities;

    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    { 
        priorities = await PriorityService.GetPriorities();

    }
}
```

Comment: The problem is not in the code you have posted.

Comment: Show GetMenus() and GetPriorities()  and how they get and use the dbContext.

Comment: It looks you are sharing same instance of dbcontext for both db requests. If you are using DI, check if for you is possible to work with `transient` instead `scoped`: https://stackoverflow.com/a/41924039/842935

Comment: Wow. Thank you dani herrera, is working .

Comment: Ok. I post it as solution.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The solution is to use a `DbContextFactory :

[Quoting docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/dbcontext-configuration/#using-a-dbcontext-factory-eg-for-blazor):

> Some application types (e.g. ASP.NET Core Blazor) use dependency injection but do not create a service scope that aligns with the desired DbContext lifetime. Even where such an alignment does exist, the application may need to perform multiple units-of-work within this scope. For example, multiple units-of-work within a single HTTP request.
>
> In these cases, AddDbContextFactory can be used to register a factory for creation of DbContext instances. For example:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddDbContextFactory<ApplicationDbContext>(
        options =>
            options.UseSqlServer(@"Server=(localdb)\mssqllocaldb;Database=Test"));
}
```

Comment: But will a transient context ever be disposed?   (Aside from the GC that is).

Comment: If OwningComponentBase is used (see: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/dependency-injection?view=aspnetcore-3.0#utility-base-component-classes-to-manage-a-di-scope), the context will be disposed of by the index page when you navigate away from it. However, the Nav page will hold the context, because you never really navigate away from it unless you reload the page.

Comment: @HenkHolterman, new technologies, new challenges: [Using Entity Framework Core with Blazor](https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/issues/10448).

Comment: I was going to edit to add the rest of that page, but the suggested edits are full. It's worth pointing out that the way in which you use that DI service changes as well, you can no longer use it directly, you have to create your instance from it.

Comment: See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69001842) answer for an example of how to use DbContextFactory with an injectable Blazor service.

Comment: It is not work for me

Answer (score 2):

> A Scoped dependency is similar to a Singleton dependency in so far as Blazor will inject the same instance into every object that depends upon it, however, the difference is that a Scoped instance is not shared by all users. ( See more: [Scoped dependencies](https://blazor-university.com/dependency-injection/dependency-lifetimes-and-scopes/scoped-dependencies/) )

In Blazor **Scoped** service is like as **Singleton** service.
If your DbContext is **Transient**, but your service class is **Scoped** that uses the **Transient** DbContext, your service class's instances will use **same** DbContext.

Because a Scoped dependency is similar to a Singleton dependency in Blazor.
But I use Transient DbContext instead of Scoped. But the problem doesn't fix for me.

I researched many times the this problem and I found solution.
Microsoft says we must use the `DbContextFactory`. We must create new DbContext for per operation. (See more: [ASP.NET Core Blazor with Entity Framework Core (EF Core)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/blazor-ef-core?view=aspnetcore-8.0#new-dbcontext-instances))

I think injecting `DbContextFactory` to razor component is wrong way. Because razor component shoudln't direct access to DbContext, repository and etc.

I am using UnitOfWork pattern and my project's repository and service layers used by another projects, therefore I can't change the repository and service layers.

I have a workaround like as below:

```
builder.Services.AddDbContext<WebSiteDbContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("WebSiteDbConnection")), ServiceLifetime.Transient);
```

I only implement `IDisposable` interface for `UnitOfWork` and `Service` classes like as below:

```
public class UnitOfWork<TEntity, TId> : IUnitOfWork<TEntity, TId>, IDisposable
      where TEntity : BaseEntity<TId>
      where TId : IEquatable<TId>
 {
     private readonly WebSiteDbContext _dbContext;

     public UnitOfWork(WebSiteDbContext dbContext)
     {
         this._dbContext = dbContext;

         this.BlogRepository = new BlogRepository(_dbContext);
     }       

     public IBlogRepository BlogRepository { get; }

     public SharpValueResponse<int> SaveChanges()
     {
         try
         {
             return new SharpValueResponse<int>(_dbContext.SaveChanges());
         }
         catch (Exception ex)
         {
             throw;
         }
     }

     // this recommended pattern for implementation of IDisposable 
     private bool disposed = false;

     protected virtual void Dispose(bool disposing)
     {
         if (!this.disposed)
         {
             if (disposing)
             {
                 _dbContext.Dispose();
             }
         }
         this.disposed = true;
     }

     public void Dispose()
     {
         Dispose(true);
         GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
     }
 }
```

My service:

```
public class BlogContentService : IBlogContentService, IDisposable
{
    private readonly IUnitOfWork<BlogContent, int> _unitOfWork;
    private readonly IMapper _mapper;

    public BlogContentService(IUnitOfWork<BlogContent, int> unitOfWork,
                              IMapper mapper)
        : base(unitOfWork, mapper)
    {
        this._unitOfWork = unitOfWork;
        this._mapper = mapper;
    }

    public SharpPageResponse<BlogContentDTO> GetAll(GetAllInput input)
    {
        var blogContents = _unitOfWork.BlogContentRepository.GetAllWithBlog(input);

        List<BlogContentDTO> blogContentsDTO = new List<BlogContentDTO>();

        blogContents.List.ForEach(x =>
        {
            blogContentsDTO.Add(base._mapper.Map<BlogContentDTO>(x));
        });

        return new SharpPageResponse<BlogContentDTO>
        {
            CurrentPage = blogContents.CurrentPage,
            TotalCount = blogContents.TotalCount,
            PageSize = blogContents.PageSize,
            List = blogContentsDTO
        };
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        _unitOfWork?.Dispose();
    }
}
```

I think no one will write unit test for razor components . Therefore I use service locator pattern for solution. (Although some developers say it is anti-pattern)

I inject `IServiceProvider` to razor component

```
@inject IServiceProvider _serviceProvider
```

And I create new scope for per methods of razor component. In the end, the problem was solved for me.

```
private async Task GetBlogs()
{
    using var serviceScope = _serviceProvider.CreateScope();

    using var blogContentService = serviceScope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<IBlogContentService>();

    _showLoading = true;

    // It is for prevent block UI. See more: https://stackoverflow.com/a/62616641/8810311
    await Task.Delay(1);

    await Task.Run(() => blogs = blogContentService.GetAll(_filter));

    _showLoading = false;
}
```

**Note: I am using Blazor Web Server.**

For more information, you can visit these links:

[Scoped dependencies](https://blazor-university.com/dependency-injection/dependency-lifetimes-and-scopes/scoped-dependencies/)

[ASP.NET Core Blazor with Entity Framework Core (EF Core)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/blazor-ef-core?view=aspnetcore-8.0#new-dbcontext-instances)

[ASP.NET Core Blazor dependency injection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/fundamentals/dependency-injection?view=aspnetcore-7.0#add-client-side-services)

Answer (score 1):

My solution for a Blazor server app was to make the ApplicatonDbContext and the service both *Transient*:

```
services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(x => x.UseSqlServer(connectionString), ServiceLifetime.Transient);
services.AddTransient<ICustomerService, CustomerService>();
```

Comment: I agree with @Bennyboy1973 for a production context. However, if demonstrating alternative components to a user in a single page, then the above solution can be useful.

Answer (score 0):

I got this error only when I attempted to access the user's information from the same service in multiple controls.  Makes sense-- they are both fighting for the same resource on initialization.

For me, the solution wasn't to change the scope-- it was to re-think what I was really doing-- why have 2 separate controls trying to access Membership features for the same user at all?