# Blazor client side refresh component

Tags: async-await, blazor, blazor-client-side, blazor-webassembly

I'm trying to figure out how to refresh the client-side component after button click.

Repo Link with example: **https://github.com/ovie91/RefreshComponent**

Site /test or from nav menu test

So I have OnInitializedAsync method that is retrieving data from API

```
protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
{
     result = await (some API Call);
}
```

Then I have a method connected to the button

```
private async void ButtonClick()
{
     await (some API Call);
     result = null;
     this.StateHasChanged(); <--- Doesnt work :<
}
```

I have tried to use **this.StateHasChanged();** but there is no reaction.
As a workaround, I can force you to navigate again to the same website but this refresh "Whole" website but not a component.

Any ideas on how to deal with it?

whole code (stripped to minimum):

```
@page "/test"
@inject HttpClient Http

@if (result == null)
    {
     <p>Loading...<p>
    }
    else
    {
    @result
     <button @onclick="(() => ButtonClick())">Click</button>
    }

@code {

  private APIObject result;

  protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
  {
     result = await (some API Call);
  }
  private async void ButtonClick()
  {
     await (some API Call);
     result = null;
     this.StateHasChanged(); <--- Doesnt work :<
  }
}
```

**Update**
I want to refresh component so OnInitializedAsync would be triggered again and that would mean I don't have to run the same code again after button click. Hope you understand what I mean.

Comment: Would help if you posted a bit more code. You're not evening showing us when / where you call StateHasChanged

Comment: In the ButtonClick - i have updated post :)

Comment: Which properties are you trying to update? - That are in the view for the user

Comment: I have added "whole code", I'm trying to update this whole Page component again.
So my data is refreshed after I click the button

Comment: You set result to null in button click

Comment: Yes, because on the refresh of the page it should be populated with the result again.
I can delete this line and it still will not work as I want :<

Answer (score 2):

To get the desired output you just have to shuffle the lines a little, from:

```
  private async void ButtonClick()
  {
     await (some API Call);   // UI checks if an update is needed (No)
     result = null;           // now an update is needed
     this.StateHasChanged(); <--- Doesnt work :<  // actually: not needed
  }
```

to:

```
  private async Task ButtonClick()
  {
     result = null;             // change the state
     //this.StateHasChanged();  // not needed, a request is pending
     await (some API Call);     // should show '<h3>Loading</h3>' now    
  }
```

Note that the UI is updated when an `await` releases the Thread.

however, from your answer we get

```
    var APICall = await Http.GetAsync("SomeAPI");
    Thread.Sleep(2000);
```

This should work when `Http.GetAsync("SomeAPI");` really is an async call and not just some stand-in pseudo code. Because `Thread.Sleep(2000);` will really freeze things.

If you want to make sure:

```
private async Task GetData()
{
    await Task.Delay(1);    // release the thread for rendering
    var APICall = await Http.GetAsync("SomeAPI");
    Random rnd = new Random();
    Thread.Sleep(2000);  // Task.Delay() is much preferred
    result = "Random Number: " + rnd.Next();
}
```

`Thread.Sleep()` is appropriate to simulate some CPU (not I/O) intensive code. So I'm not saying it's wrong but be aware of the difference.

And it is much better to make eventhandlers `async Task` instead of `async void` but that is not the direct problem here.

Comment: Henk, if you have time can you give a short explanation in why your "shuffle" works.

Comment: It's because when your code `await`s something the thread is freed and can update the UI. So set the variable to `null` _before_ awaiting to see the `<p>Loading...<p>`

Answer (score 1):

From [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/components/?view=aspnetcore-3.1#synchronization-context):

Blazor uses a synchronization context (SynchronizationContext) to enforce a single logical thread of execution. A component's lifecycle methods and any event callbacks that are raised by Blazor are executed on the synchronization context.

Blazor Server's synchronization context attempts to emulate a single-threaded environment so that it closely matches the WebAssembly model in the browser, which is single threaded. At any given point in time, work is performed on exactly one thread, giving the impression of a single logical thread. No two operations execute concurrently.

So as **enet** [asnwered](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62603232/921054), you should use `async Task` signature instead of `async void`.

Comment: I don't think the issue is related to SynchronizationContext...

Comment: Repo Link with example: **https://github.com/ovie91/RefreshComponent**

Site /test or from nav menu test

Comment: @user3574248 But it works. It updates itself with the value of `result` Even with `async void` =)

Answer (score -1):

I have moved API call to another Method and inside of OnInitializedAsync I called it.

Then when I reset the result variable to see Loading state I'm able to "refresh" component to achieve that you need to add. **this.StateHasChanged()**

Now I have a responsive component to updates that are happening :)

```
@page "/test"
@using System.Threading;
@inject HttpClient Http

@if (result == null)
        {
            <h3>Loading</h3>
        }
        else
        {
        @result
        <button @onclick="(() => ButtonClick())">Click</button>
        }




@code {

    private string result;

    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        await GetData();

    }
    private async Task GetData()
    {
        var APICall = await Http.GetAsync("SomeAPI");
        Random rnd = new Random();
        Thread.Sleep(2000);
        result = "Random Number: " + rnd.Next();
    }
    private async Task ButtonClick()
    {

        await Http.GetAsync("SomeAPIcall");
        result = null; // required to see loading state.
        this.StateHasChanged(); // when added model is refreshed and Loading state is visible.
        await GetData(); 

    }

}
```

Comment: my experience with web development is 0, I'm just learning c#, blazor and .net core.

It might be the wrong approach but its working so I have no idea what you are trying to achieve with your comments.