# Async method: Second operation was started on this context before a previous operation completed

Tags: c#, .net, blazor, blazor-server-side

I'm new to Blazor and don't have much experience working with Tasks, so hopefully I'm just making a foolish mistake. I have an async method that is called via button press, but if the method is called again within 1-2 seconds I get the following exception.

```
Error: System.InvalidOperationException: A second operation was started on this context before a previous operation completed. This is usually caused by different threads concurrently using the same instance of DbContext. For more information on how to avoid threading issues with DbContext, see https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2097913.
```

This button is rendered for each row in a Users table. I'm trying to delete multiple user records in quick succession, but receive the above error.

Here is the code for the button press (using AntBlazor)

```
 <Button Type="primary" Danger OnClick="@(async() => await RemoveAsync(user))">Remove User</Button>
```

And here is the code for the RemoveAsync method.

```
private async Task RemoveAsync(User user)
{
   await UserService.UpdateUserAsync(user);
}
```

Am I misunderstanding how async/await works? or do I need to make use of Tasks to ensure the action is complete?

Edit:

Heres the UserService.UpdateUserAsync() code

```
public async Task<bool> UpdateUserAsync(User user)
{
   _appDBContext.Users.Update(user);
   await _appDBContext.SaveChangesAsync();
   return true;
}
```

Comment: This is likely a problem at the server. Consult other answers that reference the same error message

Comment: The problem is in `UserService.UpdateUserAsync()`, not in this code.

Comment: @HenkHolterman Updated the post with the UserService.UpdateUserAsync() code

Comment: OK, so now it's about how you manage the lifetime of _appDBContext.

Comment: @HenkHolterman I'm currently using only the one DBContext and haven't made any changes other than adding the connection string.

Comment: 'the one' doesn't compute. You need to be aware of Scope and Lifettime. Click the link I posted below, there is a sample app that manually Scopes it to the Form. Not my preference but worth a look.

Comment: You need to read - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/dbcontext-configuration/ which explains about DbContexts and the section - Using a DbContext factory (e.g. for Blazor).  There are many answers to this question already on StackOverflow.

Comment: There is a lot of things to be aware of when using EFCore with Blazor server. 
Some good explanations can be found here - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/blazor-server-ef-core?view=aspnetcore-5.0

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Blazor A second operation started on this context before a previous operation completed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58046008/blazor-a-second-operation-started-on-this-context-before-a-previous-operation-co)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your code

```
public async Task<bool> UpdateUserAsync(User user)
{
   _appDBContext.Users.Update(user);
   await _appDBContext.SaveChangesAsync();
   return true;
}
```

I assume that _appDBContext is injected in the constructor, and that UserService itself is registered as Scoped.

That means that a single _appDBContext lives for the duration of your Form, accumulating tracking data. And because of `async` it runs the risk of being re-entered which is your direct problem.

One solution is not to inject a DbContext [but a DbContextFactory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/blazor-server-ef-core?view=aspnetcore-5.0#database-access).

And then it looks like:

```
public async Task<bool> UpdateUserAsync(User user)
{
   using var dbContext = _dbContextFactory.CreateDbContext(); 
   dBContext.Users.Update(user);
   var n = await dBContext.SaveChangesAsync();
   return n == 1; // just for being accurate
}
```

Now the context is scoped to each method. Much lighter on memory and you can have many overlapping operations.

Comment: Thank you! That worked perfectly and the operations are being performed without issue. The only thing that has changed as a result of this, is that the relationship between the Users and a separate Permissions entity appears to be broken. Prior to this change, all I had to do was pull the Users and EF would include the associated Permissions object under Users.Permissions.

Comment: Yes, you lose the 'lazy loading' option. Use a `.Include(u => u.Permissions)` instead.