# Can I use service to operate dbcontext in blazor like in asp.net core mvc?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, blazor, blazor-server-side

In my asp.net core mvc project, I usually use this service for business operations

```
services.AddDbContextPool<AppDbContext>(option => {
            option
            .UseMySql(
                Configuration.GetConnectionString("SqliteConstr"),
                new MySqlServerVersion(new Version(5, 5, 62)),
                //错误重试
                MysqlOpt => MysqlOpt.EnableRetryOnFailure()
            );
        });
services.AddScoped<GameService>();

public class GameService
{
    private AppDbContext DbContext { get; set; }
    public GameService(AppDbContext dbContext)
    {
        //DbContext = contextFactory.CreateDbContext();
        DbContext = dbContext;
    }

    public async Task<Game[]> GetGamesAsync()
    {
        return await DbContext.Games.ToArrayAsync();
    }
}
```

Now I plan to migrate to the blazor server, but the official tutorial asked me to use the factory mode to inject DbFactory into the blazor component, like the following, I am not very familiar with blazor, is this a requirement in blazor?

```
services.AddDbContextFactory<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
{
    options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection"));
});
// in blazor page core
@inject ItemService ItemService
using var context = DbFactory.CreateDbContext();

Filters.Loading = true;

var contact = await context.Contacts.FirstAsync(
    c => c.Id == Wrapper.DeleteRequestId);

if (contact != null)
{
    context.Contacts.Remove(contact);
    await context.SaveChangesAsync();
}

Filters.Loading = false;

await ReloadAsync();
```

Comment: Is full documented [Using a DbContext factory (e.g. for Blazor)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58047471/842935)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`AddScoped` in Blazor Server is almost equivalent to `AddSingleton` in a normal http based anything (webapi, asp mvc, razor pages etc.). Not quite, but every user will get one, and only one `DbContext`. Blazor Server works over a WebSocket connection. There is no traditional request lifetime. There is one pipe that continiously sends stuff back and forth. Hence your scoped service will be used for that one connection until it dies. Multiple UI actions will end up using the exact same instance to query with. Which can cause problems, but will most deffinitely work if you test this with only a single query.

Using the factory and creating a `DbContext` when its needed solves this nicely.

You can rewrite your `GameService` to use the factory.

```
public class GameService
{
    private readonly IDbContextFactory<ApplicationDbContext> factory;
    public GameService(IDbContextFactory<ApplicationDbContext> factory)
    {
        this.factory = factory;
    }

    public async Task<Game[]> GetGamesAsync()
    {
        using (var context = factory.CreateDbContext()) {
           return await context.Games.ToArrayAsync();
        }
    }
}
```

Then you can inject your `GameService` as a Singleton or Scoped service.

Comment: See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58047471) answer for an example of how to create a DbContextFactory.

Answer (score 2):

To register a `DbContextFactory` is the recommended way to use DbContext's from Blazor Server applications.
When calling the `AddDbContext<DbContext>()` method the `DbContext` would be registerd with a scoped lifetime. This can lead to concurrency issues that arise whenever two or more operations happen during the same time on one `DbContext`. An `InvalidOperationException` gets thrown.

By registering the `DbContextFactory` and subsequently creating new `DbContexts` whenever they are needed this risk can be mitigated.

The reason for it is that the Blazor Server hosting model only consists of one initial `HttpRequst` with subsequent changes getting delivered over the websockets connection. The lifetime of the `DbContext` is therefore tied to the time the user has the webpage opened and resembles a singleton. Because there is only one instance for the whole app, concurrency issues happen frequently.

Comment: *Please* use proper formatting. This is unreadable. The only way I know this is (probably) correct is that I already know the answer is about scopes