# .NET EF Core - Remove Repositories and Unity of Work

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, blazor

i create an app with .NET 6.0 and Blazor Server. Sometimes i got an error in my application with message *A second operation was started on this context instance before a previous operation completed.*

[Blazor Server and EF Core: A second operation was started on this context instance before a previous operation completed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71324564/blazor-server-and-ef-core-a-second-operation-was-started-on-this-context-instan)

I use normally pattern repository. I have repository for every table and unitofwork to save and other. In my previous question was explained me, that i use DbContext bad. Because it's shared dbcontext over repository and unit of work. I read many articles and usual recommendations was use only custom DbContext. I think it's not problem for me. I need to some changes in my framework but np. But i don't understand one thing. How i can do my custom generic queries for every dbset? Was there many articles about use repository with context factory and without unity of work. I don't really like the fact that all the operations are separate and access to database many times.

What is your recommendation and your expirience? Do you have any articles or tutorials about that?

I'm really just looking for how to make it the "best" and also usable for me.
Thank you very much :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`DbContext`'s are designed to be short-lived. Create a new instance of your context for each operation to resolve your issue.

Your DbContext would be something like this to make it easy to construct.

```
public class SomeDbContext : DbContext
{
     private readonly IConfiguration configuration;

     public SomeDbContext(IConfiguration configuration)
     {
         this.configuration = configuration;
         // this.Database.Migrate(); <- optional
     }

    DbSet<SomeValue> SomeValues { get; set; }

    protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
    {
        string connectionString =
            this.configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection");

        optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer(connectionString);
    }


    public async ValueTask<SomeValue> InsertSomeValueAsync(SomeValue someValue)
    {
        using var someDbContext = new SomeDbContext(this.configuration);

        EntityEntry<SomeValue> entityEntry =
            await someDbContext.SomeValues.AddAsync(entity: someValue);

        await someDbContext.SaveChangesAsync();

        return entityEntry.Entity;
    }
}
```

The InsertSomeValueAsync method could easily be made generic.

```
    public async ValueTask<T> InsertSomeValueAsync<T>(T someValue)
        where T : class
    {
        using var someDbContext = new SomeDbContext(this.configuration);

        EntityEntry<T> entityEntry =
            await someDbContext.AddAsync(someValue);

        await someDbContext.SaveChangesAsync();

        return entityEntry.Entity;
    }
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. So your recommendation is use only DbContext. Ah static extension method. It's good solution. :) But is there any way how test it (mock). Maybe i can test it with memorydatabase right? Thank you

Comment: @PetrKasnal This could be applied to an IdentityContext as well. The take away is the construction technique to create a new instance per operation. Regarding Mocking etc I actually stripped the interfaces etc to make it easier to digest

Comment: @PetrKasnal I tend to use `EFxceptionsContext` do a search on NuGet as it localizes / wraps sql errors well. I would consider this class a broker and implement and interface exposing what the consuming service requires. End to end testing I would most likely use InMemory https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/providers/in-memory/?tabs=dotnet-core-cli

Comment: Yea i understand. Yea i mean excatly this for en to end testing. Do you use factory context?

Answer (score 1):

One option is to use a `DBContextFactory` to manage the contexts.

Here's some example code from one of my applications.

`Program`

```cs
var dbConnectionString = builder.Configuration.GetValue<string>("MyConfiguration:ConnectionString");
builder.Services.AddDbContextFactory<MySqlServerDbContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(dbConnectionString), ServiceLifetime.Singleton);
```

And using it in a (generic) data broker:

```cs
public class ServerDataBroker
    : IDataBroker
{
    private IDbContextFactory<MySqlServerDbContext> _dbContextFactory;

    public ServerDataBroker(IDbContextFactory<MySqlServerDbContext> factory)
        => _dbContextFactory = factory;

//.....
    public async ValueTask<int> GetRecordCountAsync<TRecord>() where TRecord : class, new()
    {
        using var context = _dbContextFactory.CreateDbContext();
        var dbSet = context.Set<TRecord>();
        return dbSet is not null
         ? await dbSet.CountAsync()
         : 0;
    }
//.....
```

There's an MS-Docs article about it here - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/dbcontext-configuration/.

On testing, I use EF InMemory - you can use the Factory with it.  Ask if you want to be pointed to some code.

Comment: Do you use factory on every project or only for Blazor? Because i need edit my framework and i am thinking of using factory everywhere. Do you have only dbcontext? Because your (generic) data broker looks like repository. I have little problem with this. When i want add more entities than one i need for every query create db context. Yea for testing i will be use EF in memory too. Thanks

Comment: Just a small nitpick: I had trouble reading that first piece of code. `dbContext` is a very confusing name for a connectionstring.

Comment: @HenkHolterman - Thanks and agree in the ?context?, fixed.

Comment: @PetrKasnal - use it anywhere.  What I call the data pipeline database -> EF -> Broker -> ViewService is all standard DotNetCore code.  It's only the UI domain code that is specific to Blazor.   If you put together the data pipeline with a Test project there's no Blazor in sight.

Comment: @MrCakaShaunCurtis Aah sure its logically. Thank you very much.