# Implementing Single CRUD operation for more than 30 of tables

Tags: .net-core, c#-4.0, entity-framework-core, blazor-server-side, visual-studio-2022

[image: demonestration]One of my questions is closed due to insufficient information so I written another with detail.

I want to write a blazor app in c# & .netCore plateform using Visual Studio 2022.

Such app will be operated as Inventory/Financial Management System, CRM, HRM etc. so this system is based on more than 30 tables where the date will be saved via CRUD operation.

Here the question is how I can implement single CRUD for all these tables like same **UpdateTable** function (with parameters) will be usable to update the tables like **Customer**, **Supplier**, **Products** etc in my database.

something like below..

```
function DbSet UpdateTable(DbSet tableName)
 {
   _context.Update(tableName);
 }
```

Actually this will help me save my time to write several lines of code /(I mean writing CRUD) for each and every table

thanks in advance

Comment: Take a look at this article of mine describing how to build a generic data pipeline. https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/5350000/A-Different-Repository-Pattern-Implementation

Answer (score 1):

It looks you are looking for [Entity Framework Core Generic Repository](https://codingblast.com/entity-framework-core-generic-repository/):

> The advantage of having generic CRUD repository is that you can inherit from it, pass it entity type and you have CRUD repository for any entity type with a minimal amount of code.

```cs
public interface IGenericRepository<TEntity>
 where TEntity : class, IEntity
{
    IQueryable<TEntity> GetAll();

    Task<TEntity> GetById(int id);

    Task Create(TEntity entity);

    Task Update(int id, TEntity entity);

    Task Delete(int id);
}


public class GenericRepository<TEntity> : IGenericRepository<TEntity>
    where TEntity : class, IEntity
{
    private readonly CodingBlastDbContext _dbContext;

    public GenericRepository(CodingBlastDbContext dbContext)
    {
        _dbContext = dbContext;
    }

    // ... Other CRUD ops

    public async Task Update(int id, TEntity entity)
    {
        _dbContext.Set<TEntity>().Update(entity);
        await _dbContext.SaveChangesAsync();
    }

}
```

Read the blog to learn how to create the generic repository. But, be carefully. Because you are using Blazor, you should deal with [Blazor A second operation started on this context before a previous operation completed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58046008/blazor-a-second-operation-started-on-this-context-before-a-previous-operation-co)