# How to add DbContext at runtime

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

I am trying to add a `DbContext` at runtime. The reason I'm doing is because the clients use different database schemas. By so doing I cannot add it in `ConfigureServices` method of the `StartUp` because I need to know the client first then try to create a connection string with the appropriate schema in it since the `Configure` method is called every time a request is made. I have tried accessing the `IServiceCollection` but the container says no service of type `IServiceCollection` has been registered. I now tried registering IServiceCollection itself in the startUp's `ConfigureServices` method then the application refuses to start entirely. Is there a better way to add this at runtime?

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, IServiceCollection services)
        {
            // global cors policy
            app.UseCors(x => x
                .AllowAnyOrigin()
                .AllowAnyMethod()
                .AllowAnyHeader());


            app.UseAuthentication();
            app.UseMvc();

            IClientValidator clientValidator = app.ApplicationServices.GetRequiredService<IClientValidator>();
            services.AddDbContext<ClientDbContext>(options =>
                options.UseSqlServer(clientValidator.GetConnectionString()));
        }
```

The client validator is in charge of resolving the clients connection string.

Comment: You could write a factory and register it in the DI container that returns the appropriate Context at runtime.

Comment: Do both clients share the same business logic even though they have different schema designs? If no then they don't belong in the same application, if yes then you can use the strategy pattern to switch between implementations.

Comment: If both the clients have same logic. Then it would be best to change the conection string only instead of using Two DbContext.

Comment: Okay, I think let me explain the whole logic so that you can get what I mean. The clients have different schemas and are in different databases (because this is big data application) so when a client makes a request (basically a url), the system detects the client, goes to the other `Dbcontext` which knows all the information about every client and retrieves the appropriate database and schema to which it will connect to and then configures a connection string to put in the connection. So the other `DbContext` does not have the same database tables as the other.

Comment: Wow! Thanks a lot. I have decided to add the `DbContext` as usual then I'll use the `OnConfiguring` method of the `DbContext` class to set the connection string there. But one more thing, I want the connection string to be created on every request. Is it possible to add the `DbContext` as `AddTransient<>()`? Or is the `OnConfiguring` method called every time a request is made?

Comment: @TATARPRO Refer to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41923804/configuring-dbcontext-as-transient

Comment: this question is quite old though. I had done what @XingZou showed in the related article. But this gave me a headache when i was trying to test out the API recently. I discovered that whenever I put the `ServiceLifetime.Transient` whenever I try to put data into the database, for every request to the database, the service is re-initialized as I carefully watched the output window. And because of this, no data is entering into the database. What could this be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay I resolved that re-initialization problem by adding the `QueryTrackingBehaviour.NoTracking` overload of the `AddDbContext`

```
services.AddDbContext<DatabaseContext>(options =>
{
    options.UseQueryTrackingBehavior(QueryTrackingBehavior.NoTracking);
    options.UseSqlServer(databaseSettings.DefaultConnection);
});
```

The bottom line is that instead of doing that in the startup file I initialized the connection by overriding the `OnConfiguring` method of `DbContext` But I found a better solution prior to those discussed above. The solution is below

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddDbContext<BloggingContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(connectionString).UseQueryTrackingBehavior(QueryTrackingBehavior.NoTracking));
}
```