# Blazor concurrency problem using Entity Framework Core

Tags: asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, blazor, blazor-server-side

**My goal**

I want to create a new IdentityUser and show all the users already created through the same Blazor page. This page has:

1. a form through you will create an IdentityUser
2. a third-party's grid component (DevExpress Blazor DxDataGrid) that shows all users using UserManager.Users property. This component accepts an IQueryable as a data source.

**Problem**

When I create a new user through the form (1) I will get the following concurrency error:

> InvalidOperationException: A second operation started on this context before a previous operation completed. Any instance members are not guaranteed to be thread-safe.

I think the problem is related to the fact that **CreateAsync(IdentityUser user)** and **UserManager.Users** are referring the same DbContext

The problem isn't related to the third-party's component because I reproduce the same problem replacing it with a simple list.

**Step to reproduce the problem**

1. create a new Blazor server-side project with authentication
2. change Index.razor with the following code:

   ```
   @page "/"

   <h1>Hello, world!</h1>

   number of users: @Users.Count()
   <button @onclick="@(async () => await Add())">click me</button>
   <ul>
   @foreach(var user in Users) 
   {
       <li>@user.UserName</li>
   }
   </ul>

   @code {
       [Inject] UserManager<IdentityUser> UserManager { get; set; }

       IQueryable<IdentityUser> Users;

       protected override void OnInitialized()
       {
           Users = UserManager.Users;
       }

       public async Task Add()
       {
           await UserManager.CreateAsync(new IdentityUser { UserName = $"test_{Guid.NewGuid().ToString()}" });
       }
   }
   ```

**What I noticed**

- If I change Entity Framework provider from SqlServer to Sqlite then the error will never show.

**System info**

- ASP.NET Core 3.1.0 Blazor Server-side
- Entity Framework Core 3.1.0 based on SqlServer provider

**What I have already seen**

- [Blazor A second operation started on this context before a previous operation completed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58046008/blazor-a-second-operation-started-on-this-context-before-a-previous-operation-co): the solution proposed doesn't work for me because even if I change my DbContext scope from *Scoped* to *Transient* I still using the same instance of UserManager and its contains the same instance of DbContext
- other guys on StackOverflow suggests creating a new instance of DbContext per request. I don't like this solution because it is against Dependency Injection principles. Anyway, I can't apply this solution because DbContext is wrapped inside UserManager
- [Create a generator of DbContext](https://www.pmichaels.net/tag/a-second-operation-started-on-this-context-before-a-previous-operation-completed/): this solution is pretty like the previous one.
- [Using Entity Framework Core with Blazor](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/10448)

**Why I want to use IQueryable**

I want to pass an IQueryable as a data source for my third-party's component because its can apply pagination and filtering directly to the Query. Furthermore IQueryable is sensitive to CUD
 operations.

Comment: You can debug and see what line is launched twice. Probably the Add method?

Comment: unfortunately, I can't catch Visual Studio Call-Stack window output because when I click on the "click me" button visual studio will crash and report the exception that I wrote on the post. Anyway, I create a tiny project that you can clone and try it. Please remember to change line 35 at Startup.cs file 

https://github.com/Blackleones/BlazorProblemReleatedTo18340

Comment: For me it does not crash and try catch shows following exception in Add method: `Invalid attempt to call ReadAsync when reader is closed.` Probably CreateAsync is in conflict with ReadAsync?

Comment: Thank you. I've tried to run the sample through the terminal and I got the same exception that you mentioned before. Anyway as you can see CreateAsync is a method of UserManager service from Identity Framework so I don't know how to solve this problem without rewrite another UserManager.

Comment: I am not using MARS

Answer (score 18, accepted):

**UPDATE** (08/19/2020)

Here you can find the [documentation about how to use Blazor and EFCore together](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/blazor-server-ef-core?view=aspnetcore-5.0)

**UPDATE** (07/22/2020)

EFCore team introduces DbContextFactory inside Entity Framework Core .NET 5 Preview 7

> [...] **This decoupling is very useful for Blazor applications, where using IDbContextFactory is recommended,** but may also be useful in other scenarios.

If you are interested you can read more at [Announcing Entity Framework Core EF Core 5.0 Preview 7](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/announcing-entity-framework-core-ef-core-5-0-preview-7/)

**UPDATE** (07/06/2020)

Microsoft released a new interesting [video](https://youtu.be/HNJYIqeBLQc?list=PL1rZQsJPBU2St9-Mz1Kaa7rofciyrwWVx&t=1158) about Blazor (both models) and Entity Framework Core. Please take a look at 19:20, they are talking about how to manage concurrency problem with EFCore

---

### General solution

I asked Daniel Roth [BlazorDeskShow - 2:24:20](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xxIkh6GZdaM) about this problem and it seems to be a Blazor **Server-Side** problem by design.
DbContext default lifetime is set to `Scoped`. So if you have at least two components in the same page which are trying to execute an **async** query then we will encounter the exception:

> InvalidOperationException: A second operation started on this context before a previous operation completed. Any instance members are not guaranteed to be thread-safe.

There are two *workaround* about this problem:

- (A) set DbContext's lifetime to *Transient*

```cs
services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(opt =>
    opt.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")), ServiceLifetime.Transient);
```

- (B) as Carl Franklin suggested (after my question): create a singleton service with a static method which returns a new instance of `DbContext`.

anyway, each solution works because they create a new instance of `DbContext`.

### About my problem

My problem wasn't strictly related to `DbContext` but with `UserManager<TUser>` which has a `Scoped` lifetime. Set DbContext's lifetime to `Transient` didn't solve my problem because ASP.NET Core creates a new instance of `UserManager<TUser>` when I open the session for the first time and it lives until I don't close it. This `UserManager<TUser>` is inside two components on the same page. Then we have the same problem described before:

- two components that own the same `UserManager<TUser>` instance which contains a transient `DbContext`.

Currently, I solved this problem with another workaround:

- I don't use `UserManager<TUser>` directly instead, I create a new instance of it through `IServiceProvider` and then it works. [I am still looking for a method to change the UserManager's lifetime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60721511/is-it-possible-to-change-usermanagerts-lifetime) instead of using `IServiceProvider`.

> tips: pay attention to services' lifetime

This is what I learned. I don't know if it is all correct or not.

Comment: Thanks for this explanation. I was struggling with this exact problem around the UserManager several months ago. Until now this is not really fixed - I only got some workarounds.

Comment: Just one addition: Currently I'm running into this issue again. I already set all service lifetimes to be transient but still concurrency errors.

Comment: Can I try to help you in some way? do you have sample code on GitHub?

Comment: Sorry there is no sample. I figured out how to workaround, I get the error when loading data in OnParametersSetAsync - I could move the code to OnInitializedAsync without any error.

Comment: Hi Leonardo. I've been struggling with this issue. Do you have a code example for how you used IServiceProvider. Tried it myself but still getting an error although I'm sure I haven't implemented it correctly.

Comment: I'm sorry, are you talking about how to use `IServiceProvider` to create a new `DbContext` instance or how to create a new `UserManager `instance?

Comment: @LeonardoLurci I would be very interested as well in how exactly you created the UserManager by using the IServiceProvider

Comment: this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/68080935/12885902
Solved my problem finally

Comment: Hi @LeonardoLurci, how can I do the step B in general solution: create a singleton service with a static method which returns a new instance of DbContext. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4):

I downloaded your sample and was able to reproduce your problem. The problem is caused because Blazor will re-render the component as soon as you `await` in code called from `EventCallback` (i.e. your `Add` method).

```
public async Task Add()
{
    await UserManager.CreateAsync(new IdentityUser { UserName = $"test_{Guid.NewGuid().ToString()}" });
}
```

If you add a `System.Diagnostics.WriteLine` to the start of `Add` and to the end of `Add`, and then also add one at the top of your Razor page and one at the bottom, you will see the following output when you click your button.

```
//First render
Start: BuildRenderTree
End: BuildRenderTree

//Button clicked
Start: Add
(This is where the `await` occurs`)
Start: BuildRenderTree
Exception thrown
```

You can prevent this mid-method rerender like so....

```
protected override bool ShouldRender() => MayRender;

public async Task Add()
{
    MayRender = false;
    try
    {
        await UserManager.CreateAsync(new IdentityUser { UserName = $"test_{Guid.NewGuid().ToString()}" });
    }
    finally
    {
        MayRender = true;
    }
}
```

This will prevent re-rendering whilst your method is running. Note that if you define `Users` as `IdentityUser[] Users` you will not see this problem because the array is not set until after the `await` has completed and is not lazy evaluated, so you don't get this reentrancy problem.

I believe you want to use `IQueryable<T>` because you need to pass it to 3rd party components. The problem is, different components can be rendered on different threads, so if you pass `IQueryable<T>` to other components then

1. They might render on different threads and cause the same problem.
2. They most likely will have an `await` in the code that consumes the `IQueryable<T>` and you'll have the same problem again.

Ideally, what you need is for the 3rd party component to have an event that asks you for data, giving you some kind of query definition (page number etc). I know Telerik Grid does this, as do others.

That way you can do the following

1. Acquire a lock
2. Run the query with the filter applied
3. Release the lock
4. Pass the results to the component

You cannot use `lock()` in async code, so you'd need to use something like `SpinLock` to lock a resource.

```
private SpinLock Lock = new SpinLock();

private async Task<WhatTelerikNeeds> ReadData(SomeFilterFromTelerik filter)
{
  bool gotLock = false;
  while (!gotLock) Lock.Enter(ref gotLock);
  try
  {
    IUserIdentity result = await ApplyFilter(MyDbContext.Users, filter).ToArrayAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
    return new WhatTelerikNeeds(result);
  }
  finally
  {
    Lock.Exit();
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! Yes, I needed this because I am using a 3rd party component (DevEx) and I am facing this problem. Currently, I've solved with a `DbContextFactory` with the side effect of losing the change tracker. Your solution is smart and I like it. I have a question: what if you have two components on the same page where both of them interact with DbContext? I think in that case `SpinLock` doesn't solve the problem, it should be shared.. right? it seems more complicated. By the way, you give me a new point of you and I like it!

Comment: If you pass `IQueryable<T>` to other components then it won't work. You have to instead have the components ask your component for data + send a filter of some kind, and then evaluate that in your main component (inside a lock).

Comment: I'm sorry, I was talking about your example. Currently, the 3rd party library is improved and so now it has an event which asks for filters, paging, etc. But even in this case, I can have two different components who try to ask to execute a query to the same instance of dbcontext. There is a chance where both of them try to interact with dbcontext at the same time, so this is why I asked you if the `SpinLock ` should be shared. Let me know if maybe I didn't understand well your idea.

Comment: The SpinLock should be on your `OwningComponentBase<MyDbContext>` descendant component, and that is ultimately what should execute the queries for any dependent components.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps not the best approach but rewriting async method as non-async fixes the problem:

```
public void Add()
{
  Task.Run(async () => 
      await UserManager.CreateAsync(new IdentityUser { UserName = $"test_{Guid.NewGuid().ToString()}" }))
      .Wait();                                   
}
```

It ensures that UI is updated only after the new user is created.

---

The whole code for Index.razor

```
@page "/"
@inherits OwningComponentBase<UserManager<IdentityUser>>
<h1>Hello, world!</h1>

number of users: @Users.Count()
<button @onclick="@Add">click me. I work if you use Sqlite</button>

<ul>
@foreach(var user in Users.ToList()) 
{
    <li>@user.UserName</li>
}
</ul>

@code {
    IQueryable<IdentityUser> Users;

    protected override void OnInitialized()
    {
        Users = Service.Users;
    }

    public void Add()
    {
        Task.Run(async () => await Service.CreateAsync(new IdentityUser { UserName = $"test_{Guid.NewGuid().ToString()}" })).Wait();            
    }
}
```

Comment: I've tried your solution but nothing happened when I click the button. It is strange because no user is created and there wasn't any exception

Comment: I have done this in your Git project and works as expected without any exceptions.

Comment: Thank you, I've tried again and it works. 
By the way, this is a workaround and it comes with a great cost: lock user interface rendering.

Comment: Looking forward to better ideas!

Comment: I will keep you updated as soon as I will find a better solution. Anyway, thank you!

Answer (score 2):

I found your question looking for answers about the same error message you had.

My concurrency issue appears to have been due to a change that triggered a re-rendering of the visual tree to occur at the same time as (or due to the fact that) I was trying to call DbContext.SaveChangesAsync().

I solved this by overriding my component's ShouldRender() method like this:

```
    protected override bool ShouldRender()
    {
        if (_updatingDb)
        { 
            return false; 
        }
        else
        {
            return base.ShouldRender();
        }
    }
```

I then wrapped my SaveChangesAsync() call in code that set a private bool field _updatingDb appropriately:

```
        try
        {
            _updatingDb = true;
            await DbContext.SaveChangesAsync();
        }
        finally
        {
            _updatingDb = false;
            StateHasChanged();
        }
```

The call to StateHasChanged() may or may not be necessary, but I've included it just in case.

This fixed my issue, which was related to selectively rendering a bound input tag or just text depending on if the data field was being edited. Other readers may find that their concurrency issue is also related to something triggering a re-render.  If so, this technique may be helpful.

Comment: your solution is interesting and I think it solves many problems. My problem is a bit different because it isn't strictly related to dbContex.saveChangesAsync(). The problem was that I had two components on the same page, where each one was doing an async call to the database. Having the dbContext with `lifetime = scoped` then the two components generate a race condition

Answer (score 1):

Well, I have a quite similar scenario with this, and I 'solve' mine is to move everything from **OnInitializedAsync()** to

```
protected override async Task OnAfterRenderAsync(bool firstRender)
{
    if(firstRender)
    {
        //Your code in OnInitializedAsync()
        StateHasChanged();
    }
{
```

It seems solved, but I had no idea to find out the proves. I guess just skip from the initialization to let the component success build, then we can go further.

/******************************Update********************************/

I'm still facing the problem, seems I'm giving a wrong solution to go. When I checked with this [Blazor A second operation started on this context before a previous operation completed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58046008/blazor-a-second-operation-started-on-this-context-before-a-previous-operation-co) I got my problem clear. Cause I'm actually dealing with a lot of components initialization with dbContext operations. According to @dani_herrera mention that if you have more than 1 component execute Init at a time, probably the problem appears.
As I took his advise to change my dbContext Service to [Transient](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41924039/842935), and I get away from the problem.

Answer (score 1):

@Leonardo Lurci Had covered conceptually. If you guys are not yet wanting to move to .NET 5.0 preview, i would recommend looking at Nuget package 'EFCore.DbContextFactory', documentation is pretty neat. Essential it emulates AddDbContextFactory. Ofcourse, it creates a context per component.

Answer (score 1):

So far, this is working fine for me so far without any problems...

I ensure single-threaded access by only interacting with my `DbContext` via a new `DbContext.InvokeAsync` method, which uses a `SemaphoreSlim` to ensure only a single operation is performed at a time.

I chose `SemaphoreSlim` because you can `await` it.

Instead of this

```cs
return Db.Users.FirstOrDefaultAsync(x => x.EmailAddress == emailAddress);
```

do this

```cs
return Db.InvokeAsync(() => ...the query above...);
```

```cs
// Add the following methods to your DbContext
private SemaphoreSlim Semaphore { get; } = new SemaphoreSlim(1);

public TResult Invoke<TResult>(Func<TResult> action)
{
    Semaphore.Wait();
    try
    {
        return action();
    }
    finally
    {
        Semaphore.Release();
    }
}

public async Task<TResult> InvokeAsync<TResult>(Func<Task<TResult>> action)
{
    await Semaphore.WaitAsync();
    try
    {
        return await action();
    }
    finally
    {
        Semaphore.Release();
    }
}

public Task InvokeAsync(Func<Task> action) =>
    InvokeAsync<object>(async () =>
    {
        await action();
        return null;
    });

public void InvokeAsync(Action action) =>
    InvokeAsync(() =>
    {
        action();
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

@Leonardo Lurci has a great answer with multiple solutions to the problem. I will give my opinion about every solution and which I think it is the best one.

1. Making DBContext transient - it is a solution but it is not optimized for this cases..
2. Carl Franklin suggestion - the singleton service will not be able to control the lifetime of the context and will depend on the service requester to dispose the context after use.
3. Microsoft documentation they talk about injecting DBContext Factory into a component with the IDisposable interface to Dispose the context when the component is destroied. This is not a very good solution, because a lot of problems happen with it, like: performing a context operation and leaving the component before it finishes that operation, will dispose the context and throw exception..

Finally. The best solution so far is to inject the DBContext Factory in the component yes, but whenever you need it, you create a new instance with using statement like bellow:

```
public async Task GetSomething()
{
   using var context = DBFactory.CreateDBContext();

   return await context.Something.ToListAsync();
}
```

Since DbFactory is optimazed when creating new context instances, there is no significante overhead, making it a better choice and better performing than Transient context, it also disposes the context at the end of the method because of "using" statement.

Hope it was useful.