# Is it possible to change UserManager<T>'s lifetime?

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-identity

I'm trying to change `UserManager<T>` lifetime from `Scoped` to `Transient` inside the `ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection service)` but I don't know how to do that. Is it possible or I have to inject `IServiceProvider` inside every object that needs `UserManager<T>` and then create a new Scope every time I need to use the UserManager?

Answer (score 4):

You can override the lifetime scopes in the following way or you can create your own user manager:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
  var connectionString = Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection");

  services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
    options.UseSqlServer(connectionString), ServiceLifetime.Transient);

  services.AddDefaultIdentity<ApplicationUser>(options => options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedAccount = false)
    .AddRoles<IdentityRole>()
    .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>();

  var userManagerServiceDescriptor =
    services.FirstOrDefault(descriptor => descriptor.ServiceType == typeof(UserManager<ApplicationUser>));
  services.Remove(userManagerServiceDescriptor);

  var userStoreServiceDescriptor =
    services.FirstOrDefault(descriptor => descriptor.ServiceType == typeof(IUserStore<ApplicationUser>));
  services.Remove(userStoreServiceDescriptor);

  services.AddTransient<DbContext, ApplicationDbContext>();
  services.AddTransient<IUserStore<ApplicationUser>, UserStore<ApplicationUser>>();
  services.AddTransient<UserManager<ApplicationUser>>();
}
```