MudBlazor OnInitializedAsync parrallel execution AspNetCore UserManager
I have an issue with MudBlazor and AspNetCore UserManager.
In my Application I have a profile menu dropdown in the top right corner.
When i click on "Edit Profile" I get routed to my edit profile page.
So in this scenario both components are loaded at the same time.
I have created a small TryMudBlazor to test it...
When I hit the refresh button MudBlazor tries to load both components in parrallel.
Both components get the current user via AspNetCore UserManager inside the OnInitializedAsync
Problem:
Both UserManager requests work on the same DbContext so i get an error that the ApplicationUser Instance is already beeing tracked.
As the UserManager is a scoped service shouldn't there be something like thread safety by default?
I have implemented a working solution that uses a self implemented UserService with a TaskCompletionSource but I am still wondering if I am just missing something to get the thread safety by default.
public class UserService(SignInManager<ApplicationUser> signInManager, IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor)
    : IUserService
{
    public SignInManager<ApplicationUser> SignInManager { get; } = signInManager;

    private readonly TaskCompletionSource<ApplicationUser?> _taskCompletionSource = new();

    private int _isInitialized = 0;

    public async Task<ApplicationUser?> GetUserAsync(ClaimsPrincipal claimsPrincipal)
    {
        if (Interlocked.CompareExchange(ref _isInitialized, 1, 0) == 0)
        {
            var user = await SignInManager.UserManager.GetUserAsync(claimsPrincipal);
            _taskCompletionSource.SetResult(user);
            return user;
        }
        return await _taskCompletionSource.Task;
    }

    public async Task<ApplicationUser?> GetUserAsync()
    {
        var user = httpContextAccessor.HttpContext?.User;
        if (user != null)
        {
            return await GetUserAsync(user);
        }
        return null;
    }
}

Add it to Program.cs like so:
services.AddScoped<IUserService, UserService>();


Do you consider using transient usermanager?

TBH I dont know how to do it... Its getting added scoped automatically by services.AddIdentityCore<ApplicationUser>...
I tried this approach: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60721511/is-it-possible-to-change-usermanagerts-lifetime
But no effect
