# Facing threading issue in DbContext in a Blazor + CQRS architecture

Tags: entity-framework-core, cqrs, blazor-server-side, clean-architecture

I'm facing the famous "A second operation started on this context before a previous operation completed" error in my project.

I know the reason it is happening because I'm calling a same method (`GetPersons()`) on a Razor Page to load up four ComboBoxes. Here is my infrastructure/data->context:

```
public class PlaygroundBiRepository : IPlaygroundBiRepository
{

    private readonly PlaygroundBiContext _context;

    public PlaygroundBiRepository(PlaygroundBiContext context) => _context = context;

    #region Person

    public async Task<Person> GetPersonByIdAsync(int id) => await _context.Persons.FindAsync(id);
    public IQueryable<Person> GetPersons() => _context.Persons;
    public async Task<PersonRole> GetPersonRoleByIdAsync(int id) => await _context.PersonRoles.FindAsync(id);

    public IQueryable<PersonRole> GetPersonRoles() => _context.PersonRoles;
    public async Task<Role> GetRoleByIdAsync(int id) => await _context.Roles.FindAsync(id);
    public IQueryable<Role> GetRoles() => _context.Roles;

    # endregion
}
```

After reading here and there, I see no easy fix for this. I will have to lose the DI on the context if I want to use a new one every call.

The `ServiceLifetime.Transient` didn't work and the call chain is not `async`

Any pointers please.

Comment: please look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59747983/blazor-concurrency-problem-using-entity-framework-core

Answer (score 1):

the exception, it looks like the same context instance or the same DbConnection may be being used concurrently by multiple threads. However, that's just a guess.

i had similar issue and it was caused by `AddDbContextPool`after changing it to `AddDbContext` it resolved

Comment: Your guess is correct. However that is not the solution for me. I'm already using `AddDbContext`

Comment: is repository instance is also Scoped lifetime and all Asynchronous call using await

Comment: I have not mentioned an explicit scope and the issue is with `public IQueryable<Person> GetPersons() => _context.Persons;` which cannot be written as async