# Connecting ASP.NET Core to SQL server

Tags: c#, sql-server, reactjs, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I am learning ASP.NET framework. I have created a simple To Do List with React.js on the front end, and ASP.NET Core on the backend. It seems I am connecting to the database with no problems. But I have added a simple table to the server for the purposes of testing the connection which look something like this:
`1 Create a To Do List`
but when I launch the app on localhost, nothing is displayed, as depicted in this picture [loading...](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G3UGM.png), which suggests the back end is not functioning properly. Here is my connection string: `"DBConString": "jdbc:sqlserver://localhost;database=master"` and other relevant connection info```

````
        {
            services.AddControllersWithViews();
            var ConnectionString = Configuration.GetConnectionString("DBConString");
            services.AddDbContext<ToDoListDBContext>(options =>
                options.UseSqlServer(ConnectionString));
            services.AddMvc();
            services.AddCors();```

    app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
                    name: "default",
                    pattern: "{controller=ToDosController}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
            });
````

Also some screenshots that show my successful connection to the database in my IDE: [successful connection to database in Rider](https://i.stack.imgur.com/39du8.png) If anyone could share some insight into why this is not working, it'd be much appreciated!

Comment: Have  you tried debugging the application to see what the application is doing? Follow through on  your database request and see if you're getting anything in return.

Comment: You likely **don't** want to be connecting to your **master** SQL Server database as your connection string indicates.

Comment: As Timothy noted, you should not be using 'master' as your schema.  You will want to create a new database to hold your table.  With that said, your connection string seems to be a little off?  It should look more like so:
`"data source=localhost;initial catalog=master;integrated security=True;"`
'integrated security' unless you have SQL Server Authentication - with a specific user/pass set (e.g., sa and sa's password in your case to use master).
You'll also want to take a look at this to use a transient scope: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41923804/configuring-dbcontext-as-transient

Answer (score 2):

ConnectionStrings in .NET Core have a special format that needs to be followed.

Take a look here to see what you need: https://www.connectionstrings.com/sql-server/