# How to resolve specific DbContext based on query argument in GraphQL?

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, graphql, entity-framework-core

I want to use GraphQL and Entity Framework Core to query multiple databases. Each database is linked to a licensee therefore all queries receive a query argument `licenseeId`. Now I need to instruct the DI to somehow resolve the DbContext based on the `licenseeId` when a service requests a DbContext (e. g. via constructor parameter or service locator). Is this actually possible?

Here are the relevant parts as currently implemented:

**Repository class**

```cs
public MyRepository
{
    public MyDbContext DbContext { get; set; }

    public MyRepository(MyDbContext dbContext)
    {
    }
}
```

**Query class**

```cs
public class MainQuery : ObjectGraphType
{
    public MainQuery()
    {
        objectGraph.FieldAsync<ListGraphType<MyModel>>("items",
            arguments: new QueryArguments(
                new QueryArgument<NonNullGraphType<GuidGraphType>> { Name = "licenseeId" }
            ),
            resolve: async context => {
                var licenseeId = resolveFieldContext.GetArgument<Guid>("licenseeId");

                // *1, create dbContext based on licenseeId manually via factory
                var dbContext = ...;

                var repository = resolveFieldContext.ResolveServices.GetRequiredService<CucumberRepository>();

                // *2, assign context manually
                repository.DbContext = dbContext;

                return await repository.GetAllAsync();
            });
    }
}
```

As you can see, I currently need to created the DbContext manually with a factory (*1) and then assign this instance to a repository property (*2).

I would like to use pure DI here. My idea is to use the service factory in Startup somehow like

```cs
services.AddDbContext<MyDbContext>((serviceProvider, dbContextOptionsBuilder) => {
  var query = serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<?>();
  
  var connectionString = $"...;Catalog=MyDatabase_{query.GetLicenseeId()}";

  dbContextOptionsBuilder.UseSqlServer(connectionString, ...);
});
```

This would enable me to define the repository class like

```
public MyRepository
{
    public MyRepository(MyDbContext dbContext)
    {
    }
}
```

and in the resolve callbacks I could simply write

```cs
objectGraph.FieldAsync<ListGraphType<MyModel>>(...,
    resolve: async context => {
        var repository = resolveFieldContext.ResolveServices.GetRequiredService<MyRepository>();

        return await repository.GetAllAsync();
    });
```

Is this even a good idea?

Comment: Repository pattern is bad idea here.

Comment: @SvyatoslavDanyliv Yeah, I know, but I cannot change this. Lets focus on the actual issue ;)

Comment: @SvyatoslavDanyliv You pointed out that repository pattern is a bad idea here. Do you have a reference for that claim? Is it because GraphQL cannot optimize the queries then?

Comment: With EF it is always bad idea. I mean generic repository pattern. For example: https://rob.conery.io/2014/03/04/repositories-and-unitofwork-are-not-a-good-idea/

Answer (score 1):

I propose the following approach (assume that licensed is int). Note that caching `DbContextOptions` is important, because EF Core caches LINQ queries based on this object.

```cs
public interface ILicenseOptionFactory
{
    public DbContextOptions GetOptions(int licenseId);
}

public class LicenseOptionFactory : ILicenseOptionFactory
{
    private ConcurrentDictionary<int, DbContextOptions> _options = new ConcurrentDictionary<int, DbContextOptions>();

    public DbContextOptions GetOptions(int licenseId)
    {
        var options = _options.GetOrAdd(licenseId, lid =>
        {
            // any other way how to retrieve connections string based on licenseId
            string cs;
            switch (lid)
            {
                case 0:
                    cs = "connectionString0";
                    break;
                case 1:
                    cs = "connectionString1";
                    break;
                default:
                    throw new Exception($"Invalid licenseId: {lid}");
            }

            return new DbContextOptionsBuilder().UseSqlServer(cs).Options;
        });

        return options;
    }
}
```

```cs
public interface ILicenseConnectionFactory<TContext> : IDisposable, IAsyncDisposable
    where TContext : DbContext
{
    TContext GetContext(int licenseId);
}

public class LicenseConnectionFactory<TContext> : ILicenseConnectionFactory<TContext> where TContext : DbContext
{
    private readonly ILicenseOptionFactory _optionFactory;
    private static Dictionary<int, TContext> _contexts;

    public LicenseConnectionFactory(ILicenseOptionFactory optionFactory)
    {
        _optionFactory = optionFactory;
    }

    public TContext GetContext(int licenseId)
    {
        _contexts ??= new Dictionary<int, TContext>();
        if (_contexts.TryGetValue(licenseId, out var ctx))
            return ctx;

        var options = _optionFactory.GetOptions(licenseId);
        ctx = (TContext)Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(TContext), options);
        _contexts.Add(licenseId, ctx);
        return ctx;
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        if (_contexts == null)
            return;

        foreach (var dbContext in _contexts.Values)
        {
            dbContext.Dispose();   
        }

        _contexts = null;
    }

    public async ValueTask DisposeAsync()
    {
        if (_contexts == null)
            return;

        foreach (var dbContext in _contexts.Values)
        {
            await dbContext.DisposeAsync();   
        }

        _contexts = null;
    }
}
```

Registration sample, note that `Singleton` and `Scoped` is required for these services:

```cs
var serviceCollection = new ServiceCollection();

serviceCollection.AddSingleton<ILicenseOptionFactory, LicenseOptionFactory>();
serviceCollection
    .AddScoped<ILicenseConnectionFactory<MyDbContext>, LicenseConnectionFactory<MyDbContext>>();
```

Sample of repository (but better remove this abstraction at all)

```cs
public class MyRepository
{
    private readonly ILicenseConnectionFactory<MyDbContext> _factory;
    private MyDbContext _dbContext;

    public MyDbContext DbContext
    {
        get => _dbContext ?? throw new Exception("Repository is not initialized.");
    }

    public MyRepository(ILicenseConnectionFactory<MyDbContext> factory)
    {
        _factory = factory;
    }

    public void SetLicenseId(int licnseId)
    {
        _dbContext = _factory.GetContext(licnseId);
    }
}
```

And final usage. I don't know what is `resolveFieldContext` if it can be resolved by DI - you can simplify repository initialisation without using `SetLicenseId`.

```cs
public class MainQuery : ObjectGraphType
{
    public MainQuery()
    {
        objectGraph.FieldAsync<ListGraphType<MyModel>>("items",
            arguments: new QueryArguments(
                new QueryArgument<NonNullGraphType<GuidGraphType>> { Name = "licenseeId" }
            ),
            resolve: async context => {
                var licenseeId = resolveFieldContext.GetArgument<Guid>("licenseeId");

                // *1, create dbContext based on licenseeId manually via factory
                var repository = resolveFieldContext.ResolveServices.GetRequiredService<CucumberRepository>();

                // *2, assign context manually
                repository.SetLicenseId(licenseeId);

                return await repository.GetAllAsync();
            });
    }
}
```

Comment: This is basically what I have already but your code is more elaborate, +1 for that.

Answer (score 0):

After doing some more research, I come to the conclusion that resolving `DbContext` solely via `AddDbContext` / service factory is risky and pretty much a bad idea as this would require the `DbContext` to be registered as transient service. This brings side effects, some of them are mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41924039/3936440), see comments, one of the comments links to https://github.com/aspnet/DependencyInjection/issues/456 where the transient issue is also discussed.

`DbContext` needs to be transient, because a GraphQL query can contain multiple fields and therefore multiple licensee IDs, for example

```
{
  addressTypes(licenseeId: "02050fd1-b312-4571-baaf-4ee40a54eae5") {
    id,
    name,
    timestamp
  },
  banks(licenseeId: "77047070-3CBE-4E58-9805-1EA8DA621C74") {
    id,
    accountNumber
  }
}
```

So in the same `HttpRequest` request `DbContext` needs to be resolved differently for field `addressTypes` and `banks`, therefore it must be transient. But this would also mean that other code parts need to know that `DbContext` is now transient. Regarding the initial question and the repository pattern - now each repository instance would get a new `DbContext` instance injected which is (without having tested this) a bad idea.

Anyway, one of the options I found after digging in the GraphQL sources would be to retrieve the current query from `HttpContext`, parse it with a `IDocumentBuilder`, validate it with a `IDocumentValidator` and finally build the field arguments. All this is implemented by the GraphQL package in a `IDocumentExecutor` and yeah, it is super complex. I would not recommend to do it this way as you would need to copy most parts and customize it.

Another option is using `FieldMiddleware` to store the current licensee ID into a provider instance. The provider is then used in `AddDbContext` to build the connection string and return a transient `DbContext` instance. Here are some code snippets:

**Provider class to remember `LicenseeId`**

```cs
public class LicenseeIdProvider
{
    public Guid LicenseeId { get; set; }
}

services.AddScoped<LicenseeIdProvider>();
```

**Schema with FieldMiddleware to remember `licenseeId` in provider instance**

```
public class DefaultSchema : Schema
{
    public DefaultSchema(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
        : base(serviceProvider)
    {
        ...

        FieldMiddleware.Use(next =>
        {
            return resolveFieldContext =>
            {
                if (resolveFieldContext.HasArgument("LicenseeId"))
                {
                    var licenseeId = resolveFieldContext.GetArgument<Guid>("LicenseeId");
                    var licenseeIdProvider= resolveFieldContext.RequestServices.GetService<LicenseeIdProvider>();

                    licenseeIdProvider.LicenseeId = licenseeId;
                }

                var result = next(resolveFieldContext);

                return result;
            };
        });
    }
}
```

**DbContext registration with service factory to create instance based on licenseeId**

```
services.AddDbContext<MyDbContext>((sp, dbContextOptionsBuilder) =>
{
    var licenseeIdProvider = sp.GetService<LicenseeIdProvider>();
    var licenseeId = licenseeIdProvider.LicenseeId;

    var connectionString = $"...;Catalog=MyDatabase_{licenseeId}";

    dbContextOptionsBuilder.UseSqlServer(connectionString, ...);
}, ServiceLifetime.Transient);
```