# How to distinguish between multiple databases with the same structure and same context in the URL for an ASP.Net Core Web API

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, entity-framework-core

I'm trying to make a web api in asp.net core which can target multiple databases on the same server with the exact same structure. As such they should be able to share the same context and controllers. Making separate contexts and controllers for each database would quickly get out of hand and make it a pain to maintain. As such I should be able to do this in Startup.cs.

```
services.AddDbContext<DatabaseContext>(opt => opt.UseMySQL(Configuration.GetConnectionString("db1")));
services.AddDbContext<DatabaseContext>(opt => opt.UseMySQL(Configuration.GetConnectionString("db2")));
services.AddDbContext<DatabaseContext>(opt => opt.UseMySQL(Configuration.GetConnectionString("db3")));
```

The problem I'm running into is how I can distinguish which database is being queried. Ideally I would like to have it such that the url can be ...{database}[controller]... where the database parameter can be used to determine which database is being queried. I've tried looking into the multi-tenant approach however I can't work out how to adapt it to my specific use case.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: May I ask why you need to set several databases? Per my understanding, it's better to redirect to specific action in your server but not set the database name into the url so that anyone can see the database name. Could you pls share your scenario to help us know your issue better?

Comment: @TinyWang I'm trying to use it to retrieve static information for GTFS, with each database signifying a different region. Is there a better way to do something like this?

Comment: If I faced the same scenario, I prefer to divide them into several api project and each project provide specific api to one database. Just like the micro service model. And have a business project to receive requests from the client and decide to call which api to query data. Anyway, this is just my point of view.

Comment: Check this my answer, maybe it will be helpful for you: https://stackoverflow.com/a/68089228/10646316

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at this:

https://entityframeworkcore.com/knowledge-base/58123230/connect-multiple-databases-to--net-core-project-via-entity-framework-core

You can do it with multiple DB Contexts from inheriting the principal DB Context where you define the DbSets.

Create base context and including all settings into this, DBSET:

```
public abstract class BaseContext : DbContext
{
    public BaseContext(DbContext options)
    : base(options)
    { }
    public DbSet<object> FirstDbSet { get; set; }
    ...
}
```

inherit from BaseContext for both DBs(Databases):

```
public class NavaContext : BaseContext
{
    public NavaContext (DbContext<NavaContext> options) : base(options)
    {

    }
}
```

```
public class StackContext : BaseContext
{
    public StackContext(DbContext<StackContext> options) : base(options)
    {

    }
}
```

and register both in Startup.cs:

```
public IServiceProvider ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddDbContext<NavaContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("LATAMConnectionString")));
    services.AddDbContext<StackContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("EUConnectionString")));

    // Autofac
    var builder = new ContainerBuilder();

    // needed only if you plan to inject ICollection<BaseContext>
    builder.RegisterType<NavaContext>().As<BaseContext>();
    builder.RegisterType<StackContext>().As<BaseContext>();

    builder.Populate(services);


    return new AutofacServiceProvider(builder.Build());
}
```

add connection strings in appsettings.json:

```
"ConnectionStrings": {
  "NavaConnectionString": "Server=(localdb)\\mssqllocaldb;Database=ContosoUniversity1;Trusted_Connection=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=true",
  "StackConnectionString": "Server=(localdb)\\mssqllocaldb;Database=ContosoUniversity1;Trusted_Connection=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=true"
}
```

and now you can inject both contexts:

```
public class ReportRepository : IReportRepository
{
    private readonly NavaContext latamDbContext;
    private readonly StackContext euDbContext;

    public ReportRepository(NavaContext latamDbContext, StackContext euDbContext)
    {
        this.latamDbContext = latamDbContext;
        this.euDbContext = euDbContext;
    }
}
```

or if you plan to inject collection of contexts:

```
public class ReportRepository : IReportRepository
{
    private readonly ICollection<BaseContext> dbContexts;

    public ReportRepository(ICollection<BaseContext> dbContexts)
    {
        this.dbContexts = dbContexts;
    }
}
```

to access specific context:

```
var _stackContext= dbContexts.FirstOrDefault(x => x is StackContext) as StackContext;
var _navaContext= dbContexts.FirstOrDefault(x => x is NavaContext) as NavaContext;
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. I'll try looking into this solution when I get a chance.

Comment: The link could disappear tomorrow. Please provide the answer in here instead of posting links to external resources.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to create connection when there are multiple databases in dot net core is with `IDesignTimeDbContextFactory`

```
public class BloggingContextFactory : IDesignTimeDbContextFactory<BloggingContext>
{
    public BloggingContext CreateDbContext(string[] args)
    {
        // logic to determine which connection string to use
        var optionsBuilder = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<BloggingContext>();
        optionsBuilder.UseSqlite("connectionString");

        return new BloggingContext(optionsBuilder.Options);
    }
}
```

Inject BloggingContextFactory using register services and pass args[] for logic to use connection string