# Use different connection string based on country parameter and do you need to use "using" in EF Core?

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, dbcontext

Having a few Databases for example:

- DB_EN
- DB_FR
- DB_DE

.

So I created something to get the correct Database by `countryCode` :

```
using (var context = new ApplicationContext(_DbContextConfigurationService.GetConnectionString(countryCode)))
{
    return await context
        .Set<T>()
        .Where(expression)
        .FirstOrDefaultAsync();
}
```

I do this now for every action (CRUD), using the `using` statement and creating a new ApplicationContext.

The question is, is there a more proper way to get the correct Database by `countryCode` (maybe in the constructor? And is `"using"` needed? Because when I see the Microsoft documentation they are not using it.

I also plan to add a UoW layer. Hope it's a bit clear what I mean.

Comment: What you could do is have a class that accesses the connection strings from the config. In there you could have methods for each country and return it that way

Comment: You could consider having multiple `DbContext`s, which in my view is a way to go. You have separate databases for each language, so it makes sense to have separate `DbContext`s. Each of them is provided with its own `ConnectionString` and can be injected in constructor of your controller/service. Depending on the way you pass `countryCode` to your invocation context, you could also build a factory that is also injected in the constructor and have a method `GetDbContext` which internally has all of the `DbContext`s injected and `countryCode` and returns proper context.

Comment: Check all [question and answers of this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/q/68085583/10646316)

Comment: @Dandry can you provide a smaa example with what you mean with GetDbContext? I pass the countryCode in the Services.

Comment: There are several misconceptions in the question. A DbContext *is a Unit-of-Work already*, one covering multiple entities. So *yes*, `using` is needed because it marks that Unit of Work. `Because when I see the Microsoft documentation they are not using it` quite the opposite

Comment: And since DbContext is a Unit-of-Work you *do* need a different instance every time

Comment: `is there a more proper way to get the correct Database by countryCode (maybe in the constructor?` you already use the constructor to pass a different connection string per country. That's perfectly fine if you want complete isolation between countries, as your DbContext configuration doesn't even know that several databases are involved.