# Repository pattern sharing changes across scoped instances

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

I am using a pretty standard generic repository pattern (for example https://codewithmukesh.com/blog/repository-pattern-in-aspnet-core/#What_would_happen_if_we_didnt_have_an_UnitOfWork_Abstraction)

In **program.cs** I define my DB context and generic repository services as scoped.

```
...
  services.AddDbContext<MyDbContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(configuration.GetConnectionString(connectionName))                                                            ;

  services.AddScoped(typeof(IGenericRepository<,>), typeof(GenericRepository<,>));
...
```

In a worker service I create two scoped instances during code execution;

```
using (var serviceScope = _serviceProvider.CreateScope())
{
  var personDataService = serviceScope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<IGenericRepository<Person, MyDbContext>>();
  var auditLogDataService = serviceScope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<IGenericRepository<AuditLog, MyDbContext>>();
  ...
}
```

When I make a call that generates an SQL exception on the first service I want to log the error in the second service, for example;

```
try {
   await personDataService.InsertAsync(myNewPerson);
} 
catch (Exception ex)
{
   var newAuditLog = new AuditLog("Exception occurred inserting a new user", ex);
   await auditLogDataService.InsertAsync(newAuditLog);
}
```

However, when `personDataService` generates a `SQLException`, for example;

> SqlException: Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'Name'"

then the `catch` block triggers and I get the same error again when I run `InsertAsync()` on the 2nd `auditLogDataService` service.

> SqlException: Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'Name'"

It appears that the changes from the first service are also in the second service. I'm assuming that `MyDbContext` is shared.

How do I create an independent instance of `auditLogDataService` so I can save the 2nd change without the first?

Comment: Maybe the easiest solution is to create a separate context for logging. I think that's not a bad idea anyway. Keeps things separated in the application. That allows you to have a shared (scoped) context for one unit of work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably use `services.AddDbContext<YourDbContext>()`, which makes it a scoped service by default.

This means that within one scope (which you create), you get the same instance of the DbContext every time you or another service requests it.

Mark it as transient instead, to get a new instance every time you request one. See [Configuring Dbcontext as Transient](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41923804/configuring-dbcontext-as-transient):

```
services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
     options.Use(...), 
     ServiceLifetime.Transient);
```

Meta-commentary: please don't use repository patterns with Entity Framework. EF already exposes a repository through `DbSet<T>`. How are you going to support `Include()`s? Projections (`Select()`)? Groupings (`GroupBy`)?

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to answer, I have added my DB context setup to the post. 
FYI I've already handled Include etc via optional parameters and expressions. Probably not perfect but it creates a nice consistent API across all our apps for our junior devs.

Comment: _"nice consistent API"_ - just like the very well documented Entity Framework, for which you can find code samples all over the web? Now your junior devs will have to learn a company-specific layer over Entity Framework which doesn't transfer to other jobs, and wonder why stuff they find on the web doesn't work on your layer because you didn't think of it.

Comment: Note that this solution breaks the natural relationship between scope and unit of work, i.e. the possibility to save everything in one scoped web request simply by one SaveChanges(Async) call (since the context is the UoW, as a DbSet is indeed a repository). It requires extra wiring to keep transient contexts together in one transaction.

Comment: Yeah good point @Gert, if you use multiple repositories or services that want to exchange entities, that won't work anymore.

Answer (score 0):

Could you try sending the DBContext object via constructor call for each and every repositories? For instance, whenever generic repository is used for any class Type, make it's constructor call and pass the DBContext object right away. So, every time the object of repository defined for that interface is called, you get the current DBContext.

Answer (score 0):

You could inject a dbContextFactory into your repository and make a new DbContext from your factory there.