# DbContext Concurrent Access Issue

Tags: concurrency, entity-framework-core, dbcontext

I have this query

```
var user = await DbContext.Set<ApplicationUser>()
                   .FirstOrDefaultAsync(x => x.UserID.ToUpper() == userID.ToUpper());
```

that throws the following exception when concurrent requests happen

```
System.InvalidOperationException
  HResult=0x80131509
  Message=A second operation was started on this context instance before a previous operation completed. This is usually caused by different threads concurrently using the same instance of DbContext. For more information on how to avoid threading issues with DbContext, see https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2097913.
  Source=Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore
  StackTrace:
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure.Internal.ConcurrencyDetector.EnterCriticalSection()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.SingleQueryingEnumerable`1.AsyncEnumerator.<MoveNextAsync>d__18.MoveNext()
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.ShapedQueryCompilingExpressionVisitor.<SingleOrDefaultAsync>d__15`1.MoveNext()
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.ShapedQueryCompilingExpressionVisitor.<SingleOrDefaultAsync>d__15`1.MoveNext()
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()
   at SF.Auth.Infrastructure.Data.RBA.Repository.IdentityManagerRepository.<GetUser>d__8.MoveNext() in C:\Users\Bel12\source\repos\sf-identity\SF.Auth.Infrastructure\Data\RBA\Repository\IdentityManagerRepository.cs:line 77
```

The `repository` and `DbContext` configuration in the `Startup` file looks like the following

```
services.AddDbContext<UserManagementDbContext>(options => options
        .UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("home_sql_context")), 
                                  ServiceLifetime.Transient, ServiceLifetime.Transient);

services.AddTransient<IIdentityManagerRepository, IdentityManagerRepository>();
```

I was able to reproduce the exception by sending two requests at the same moment using JMeter

I am using `net6.0` and `Microsoft SQL Server`

Does any one has a solution? I have read lots of related StackOverflow answers but I was not able to resolve the issue

[image]

Comment: Why `AddTransient<IIdentityManagerRepository,`? Why not scoped?

Comment: I try to change it to Scoped and the program throws an exception `System.InvalidOperationException: Cannot resolve 'SF.AuthServer.Providers.Auth.TokenProvider' from root provider because it requires scoped service 'SF.Auth.Infrastructure.Data.RBA.Repository.IIdentityManagerRepository'.

Comment: Usually such exception is thrown if someone forgot to put `await` before async method or used something like `Task.WaitAll`.

Comment: I am not using Task.WaitAll and await is there on the query

Comment: I don't think this is the one method in your application, which uses the same DbContext. Problem can be somewhere. else.

Comment: I put the code inside a try catch block and the exception originates there. I have attached an image on the question

Comment: It is wrong assumption. Some other method executed database call and not awaited. Task is running. Then your current method is trying to execute another query on the same DbContext - and you have this exception.

Comment: I have reviewed all other async methods in relation to the request send and I could not find any without await

Comment: Can you try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41924039/10646316) configuration for EF Core?

Comment: Walk up your call stack leading to that breakpoint and check every line where DbContext is being referenced. You likely have an Async method that isn't being awaited. including whatever called this method if it hasn't awaited and had continued off to do other things. DbContexts generally shouldn't be Transient. It does allow for parallel operations but IMO the trade-off of a lot more code to work around detacked entity references or references tracked by different DbContext instances is heavier and more error prone.